# Vue / Laravel Passport error (500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: vue.js, laravel-passport

Everything was working fine then I added a new column with my table and proceed to use the `php artisan migrate:fresh` command.

Table `oauth_clients` has been cleared so I did a `php artisan passport:install`. It generated a new client secret and changed my ENV client secret file.

I also created a faker account using `factory(App\User::class, 5)->create();` command but I'm still having this 500 error. I check the log in the client it this is what it says.

[image]

Comment: You need to check the server-side logs.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please guide me on this?

Comment: I have now distinguished the problem. It has something to do with the relationship of database. Thank you very much for your hint!